# TestNG dependsOnMethods query

Tags: testng

TestNG dependsOnMethods not getting called as expected.

For given pice of code:

```
public class Test { 

@Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test1");
    }


@Test(dependsOnMethods="test1")
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test2");
    }

@Test(dependsOnMethods="test1")
    public void test3() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test3");
    }

}
```

Output:
test1
test2
test3

Instead of
Output:
test1
test2

test1
test3

When all the tests are run then if two or more methods depend on another same method it calls the dependent method only once and not for every test. Same is the case with dependsOnGroups.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Testng calculates all the dependencies in the start and creates an order of execution.

dependsOnMethods only gaurantees that a dependent test will run after the test it says it is dependent on.  It does not gaurantee that the parent test is run before each dependent test.

If you want something to run before each test, it is kind of a setup step then and you should evaluate using @Before annotations rather than dependsOn.  for eg. @BeforeMethod would ensure that the method runs before each @Test.  HTH.